# Updating index.html isnt updating site

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am updating my index.html page and it isnt updating my site.

I have cleared the cache, waited 48 hours, used different devices at different locations, checked my .htaccess file, checked the file is in public_html, checked the permissions...

Why would this happen? I only made a really simple addition to the html and css of the site but I didn't set up the website in the first place.

I've also noticed that whatever random file name/mix of letters i put on the end of the url, it still gives me the old site. Does this have something to do with it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say that you "checked" your .htaccess file? Have you tried removing it temporarily?

Comment: I mean I checked that it was pointing to index.html

Comment: And have you tried removing it?

Answer (score 0):

If your website is being served through a CDN (Content Delivery Network), you may need to refresh its cache so that the changes are reflected around the world.

Answer (score 0):

Test is using a proxy , it may happen because your isp keep the webpage saved in cache , it may not be your browser, but your isp

Comment: proxy is giving me the same old site. I've also noticed that whatever random file name/mix of letters i put on the end of the url, it still gives me the old site. Does this have something to do with it?

Comment: Try to restart your server, maybe it's keepping it on cache